# Consolidate the contents of the files instead of editing one by one

Tags: powershell

```
$file = 'G\*\configs.txt'
$find = '192.168.152.161:8011'
$replace = '{appconfigs.writes}'

(Get-Content $file).replace($find, $replace) | Set-Content $file
```

When I run the edit script on all the files together, the script unites them and does not edit one by one.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to potentially process multiple files.
Therefore, you cannot use `Get-Content` straight away. You need to wrap this in a loop.

Here is an example on how to do this.

```
$find = '192.168.152.161:8011'
$replace = '{appconfigs.writes}'

foreach ($File in Get-ChildItem -Path 'G\*\configs.txt') {
    $Content = Get-Content -Path $File.FullName -Raw
    #IndexOf to avoid using Set-Content on files that did not change
    if ($Content.IndexOf($find) -gt -1) {
        $Content.replace($find, $replace) | Set-Content $file.FullName
    }
}
```